# Two papers with identical introduction and related work

Tags: publications, writing

I wrote a paper (for an economics journal) that contained two main theorems. It was too long - over 60 pages. So I split it to two papers - one for each main theorem (and the related lemmas). Now, the introduction and related-work section in these two papers are almost identical, since the topic is the same. Will this be considered self-plagiarism (e.g. by automatic plagiarism detection tools)? What is a good way to write these papers preventing duplication?

Comment: I assume that each of your main theorems has its own story of how it will be useful to the readers of the paper. If you get this story straight in the introduction and related work, these sections should be substantially different.

Comment: If you give the source, it is not plagiarism.  Like this: "The Introduction and Related Work are repeated verbatim from paper [4]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat a different aspect of the topic, it is absolutely fair to split it up in two parts. The introduction will sound quite the same, but this is also the case for most introductions in a specific research field. If you define well the objective of the paper you are presenting, you should be fine.

Here is an example of a paper (among many) splitted in two parts that takes interest in one main topic : [Part 1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21772924) and [Part 2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021929011006233)